# Given a groupId and authenticated user, how do I check the user's membership and role (owner vs member) in one network call?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

As far as I know, Microsoft Graph lets me query for `/groups/{groupid}/members` or `/groups/{groupid}//owners` separately, but not both in one call. Is this possible?

In my context, I know the `groupId` and the authenticated calling `userId`. How do I check whether this user belongs to the group and if so, their owner/member role in one network call? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

One option to assume would be to expand and include `members` and `owners` properties via [`$expand` query option](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/overview/query_parameters) but unfortunately the following query is not supported:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}?$select=owners,members&$expand=owners,members
```

since max only `1` object is allowed to be expanded per [`Group` resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-1.0)

[JSON batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching) comes to the rescue here, the following example demonstrates how to retrieve Group members and owners within a single request:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "requests": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/groups/{group-id}/members"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/groups/{group-id}/owners"
    }
  ]
}
```